# Передача данных между компонентами в Angular 5

Tags: angular5

вот если есть два компонента, и в первом компоненте есть какой то метод, и допустим, этот метод получает данные. И надо эти полученные данные отправить во второй соседний компонент.

```
<child1></child1>
<child2></child2>
```

Как это сделать? И вообще стоит ли так делать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Через декоратор [@Input @Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делать можно двумя способами:

1. Через общий сервис. Создаете сервис, в обоих компонентах используете данный сервис для передачи данных.
2. Используете входящие и исходящие параметры компонентов.

Какой подход выбрать - зависит от задачи.

1. Если компоненты находятся в разных компонентах, то первый способ.
2. Если компоненты находятся рядом, в одном компоненте, то можно использовать оба способа.

Пример первого способа:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m7i3ar?file=app%2FcomponentB.component.ts

Пример второго способа:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtceyk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: если компоненты **рядом** - то входящие/исходящие параметры все еще неудобны

Comment: @Grundy Возможно и не удобны. Но тем не менее так можно делать - и так делается.

Comment: @Grundy можете метки Angular 5, Angular 4 и Angular 2 сделат синонимами?

Comment: Но из ответа выходит, что если компоненты _рядом_, то только входные/выходные параметры нужно использовать, что в общем случае будет весьма проблематично

Comment: Для синонимизации можно создать тему на мете, либо предложить самому. Там несколько голосов нужно

Comment: @Grundy у меня не хватает репутации давать на синонимы)

Comment: Тем, кстати, [уже поднималась](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6810/186999), но что-то не взлетела